# How to apply material on an object that is under armature

Tags: materials, armature

I have an object and I have made a simple animation using it so it is under an armature on the outliner editor.

When I apply a material to this object, I can't see the color of material but if I render the image I can see the correct colored object.

How can I apply a material to an object under an armature and see the result on the screen?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, but an object being parented to an armature shouldn't effect it's viewport rendering. Maybe check your viewport settings in the properties panel. [This is what the default looks like](http://puu.sh/k5tVD.png). Are you talking about not being able to see proper texturing or shading? In that case try changing your view modes between [texture and material modes](http://puu.sh/k5u2B.png). These viewport modes apply more accurate views of your scenes materials and lighting effects and will usually show all additional details.

Comment: When I change viewport mode it worked. Thanks a lot. If you write an answer as change viewport mode etc. I will accept it.

Comment: No problem, I just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see your materials with proper texturing and shading change your viewport mode to either *Texture* or *Material*.

[image: shading pie menu]